# FTR calculation using Google Query function

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, crosstab, calculated-field, google-query-language

I am trying to create crosstabs `pivot tables` using `Google Query function` to calculate Employees `First Time Resolution (FTR) rate` based on the `number of Issues received while booking Opportunities` vs `Total Opportunities booked`.

```
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| OppName | OppID | EmpName | MonthYear | Status | Issue |
+=========+=======+=========+===========+========+=======+
| abc     | 1000  | alex    | 2020-Jan  | active | yes   |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| def     | 1001  | alex    | 2020-Jan  | won    | yes   |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| ghi     | 1002  | alex    | 2020-Feb  | active | no    |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| jkl     | 1004  | mini    | 2020-Feb  | lost   | yes   |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| mno     | 1005  | mini    | 2020-Feb  | won    | yes   |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| pqr     | 1006  | mini    | 2020-Mar  | active | no    |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| stu     | 1007  | mini    | 2020-Mar  | won    | yes   |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| vwx     | 1008  | joe     | 2020-Jan  | won    | no    |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
| yza     | 1009  | joe     | 2020-Mar  | lost   | yes   |
+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+-------+
```

OUTPUTS:

```
1. NO OF ISSUES:
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| NO OF ISSUES | 2020-Jan | 2020-Feb | 2020-Mar |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| alex         |        2 |          |          |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| mini         |          |        1 |        1 |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| TOTAL        |        2 |        1 |        1 |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

FORMULA:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select D,count(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' AND F = 'yes' Group by D PIVOT C LABEL D 'NO OF ISSUES'",0))
```

...

```
2. TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES:
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES | 2020-Jan | 2020-Feb | 2020-Mar |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| alex                |        2 |        1 |          |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| joe                 |        1 |          |          |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| mini                |          |        1 |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| TOTAL               |        3 |        2 |        2 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

FORMULA:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select D,count(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' Group by D PIVOT C LABEL D 'TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES'",0))
```

...

```
3. FTR%:
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| FTR%         | 2020-Jan | 2020-Feb | 2020-Mar |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| alex         |          |  100.00% |          |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| joe          |  100.00% |          |          |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| mini         |          |          |   50.00% |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| AVERAGE FTR% |  100.00% |  100.00% |   50.00% |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

FORMULA:

```
NEED QUERY FORMULA TO CALCULATE FTR AND GENERATE THIS TABLE.
```

So i plan to club all 3 tables into a single query formula like this once the 3rd table formula is figured out:

```
={

{TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select COUNT(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' AND F = 'yes' Group by D LABEL COUNT(B) 'FTR CALC' FORMAT COUNT(B) ' '",0))};
{TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select D,COUNT(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' AND F = 'yes' Group by D PIVOT C LABEL D 'NO OF ISSUES'",0))};
{TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select COUNT(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' AND F = 'yes' Group by D LABEL COUNT(B) 'TOTAL'",0))};

{TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select COUNT(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' Group by D LABEL COUNT(B) ' ' FORMAT COUNT(B) ' '",0))};
{TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select D,COUNT(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' Group by D PIVOT C LABEL D 'TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES'",0))};
{TRANSPOSE(QUERY($A$2:$F,"select COUNT(B) WHERE D IS NOT NULL AND E!='lost' Group by D LABEL COUNT(B) 'TOTAL'",0))}

}
```

The formula in each cell of the 3rd table will be:

```
=IFERROR(IF(100%-(I2/I7)*100%=0,"",100%-(I2/I7)*100%),"")
```

or simply,

```
=100%-(I2/I7)*100%   'above 2 crosstabs starting from column H
```

Can someone help me generate the 3rd table?

Comment: Very sorry, hard for me to understand your examples. Where is "joe" in number of issues? Would you be able to create a sample google spreadsheet with your expected results from a set of data? Also, it seems that you don't need to post the first two formulas as they may not be needed to answer the question, right? From what I can tell, you need to create a third table based on the two generated previously. So please post **only** the minimal amount of info. What is First time resolution? Could you give some more context/change the example into something more simple?

Comment: @iansedano, no i need all 3 tables. FTR is basically `no of issues pending in booked opportunities` vs `total opportunities booked`. Joe is not there in `no of issues` because he may not have any `pending issues` for all his booked opportunities.

Comment: ...and the reason why i am clubbing all 3 tables (and their TOTALS also) like this `{ {table1} ; {table2} ; {table3} } is because they can expand their rows dynamically without overlapping each other.

Comment: I was confused by your equations in table 3, since I didn't know what was in columns H and I.  So I tried to do an answer from scratch, but I may have misunderstood your intentions.  Also, is there a special reason that you want a final single formula to generate all three tables, plus their total lines, from one formula?

Comment: @kirkg13 yes i need a single formula so that the tables are more dynamically stacked one above the another. I also need the TOTALS row for each table containing SUMs for the Count columns and AVG for the FTR% column.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to stack the tables exactly as you are showing, since each of your tables might come out a different width - some months might have issues or opportunities, but no resolutions, etc. so those would have more columns than the resolution table.  If you want to show all months, even if there are no resolution values for them, then I don't think you can use the types of query formulas you are starting with.  I would suggest producing the dynamic tables separately, with their TOTAL lines, and then merge them if ncessary, based on knowing the width of the widest table.

Comment: @player0 is it possible for you to help with your brilliant ideas in creating these stacked tables, especially the FTR table?

Answer (score 1):

Well I found it a bit confusing, but if I've understood correctly, I have an answer that may do what you want.  I'm not clear whether you want this all done on the fly, or whether you allow for the intermediate tabale results to appear in your sheet - you referred to tables 1, 2, and 3.  I have a formula for the third table, but it is based on two intermediate tables.  Possibly the formulas can be combined to eliminate the intermediate tables.

Consider this formula, in H9 on my sample sheet:

```
={
  {"FTR%",TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(D3:D,D3:D<>""))))}; 
  {                 SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C3:C,C3:C<>""))),
   ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF((N3:P5/I3:K5)=0,"",N3:P5/I3:K5),""))}
 }
```

The first transpose/sort gets the months across the top, the second sort gets the names of all the agents, into column 1, and the arrayformula divides the # of resolutions by the # of opportunities from two intermediate tables, to fill in the FTR values.

Note that I've limited the range of the intermediate tables, but only because of including elements below them for display purposes.  These ranges could be made unlimited, like the input data table.

If this is not on the right track, let us know what more you need.

See my sample sheet here.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16otcDfnmWMEL0YpgH3aH0vn4Gip6XEY7yPDLQ9Y-83A/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: i tried stacking your table formulae one above the other, but getting error as can be seen from your Sheet1. To demonstrate, i have only rearranged your tables one above the other, leaving a blank row between each table. The tables also need to have the Totals row just like in a normal pivot. Hope this is clear.

As you can see, i added a new row with emp name `Mike` to the Input table. So the tables need to auto-adjust accordingly with the totals and counts updated.

Comment: Give me some time.  I need to take a different approach, since your tables 1 and 2 may not always have the same number of agents or months, they way you have them now.

Comment: Yes, that is what i was trying to say when i mentioned `Dynamic` tables. :-)

Comment: As the pivotting will be on Year-Month, Is there a way to show a fixed number of 12 months for a particular year, even if some of the months may not show any data? This is to avoid the error `In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows` due to column mismatches between the stacked tables.

Answer (score 1):

### An Apps Script solution

Since you already have an answer for the functions, which I believe will get you to the result you want, I want to present an alternative solution for your issue. Besides being far easier (for me) to go with Apps Script, it seems like a much more appropriate tool for these type of jobs.

<sup>Though I know there are many that are fans of doing **everything** with formulas, power to you.</sup>

*I based the example on the sample spreadsheet given in the answer @kirkg13 gave, as it was much easier to follow than in the question*

First, [follow this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview#your_first_script) if you don't know how to create an Apps Script project.

Then fill your data in a sheet like this one:

[image]

With the sheet name "InputData". The columns must be the same, though the amount of data is up to you.

Create another sheet called "Report" and leave it blank.

Copy this code into your script editor:

```js
function main() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("InputData").getDataRange()
  
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  var headers = data.shift()
  
  var dateRange = getDateRange(data)
  var agentData = buildAgentData(data)
  
  var reportData = buildReport(dateRange, agentData, headers)
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Report").getRange(1,1,reportData.length, reportData[0].length).setValues(reportData)
}

function getDateRange(data) {
  
  var dates = data.map( (record) => {return record[3]} )
  var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, dates))
  var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, dates))
  
  var counter = minDate
  var dateRange = []
  while (counter <= maxDate) {
    dateRange.push(new Date(counter))
    counter.setDate(counter.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return dateRange
}

function buildAgentData(data) {
  
  agentData = {}
  
  data.forEach( (record) => {
    var name = record[2]
    var date = record[3]
    var resolved = record[6]
   
    if (!(name in agentData)) {
      agentData[name] = {[date]:{"cases":1, "resolved":resolved}}
    } else if (date in agentData[name]) {
      agentData[name][date]["cases"] += 1
      if (resolved == 1) {
        agentData[name][date]["resolved"] += 1
      }
    } else {
      agentData[name][date] = {"cases":1, "resolved":resolved}
    }
  })
  
  return agentData
}

function buildReport(dateRange, agentData, headers) {
  
  // BUILDING DATA ROWS
  
  var opportunities = [];
  var resolutions = [];
  var ftr = [];
    
  for(agent in agentData) {
    
    var rowOpp = [agent];
    var rowRes = [agent];
    var rowFtr = [agent];
    
    dateRange.forEach( (date) => {
    
      try {rowOpp.push(agentData[agent][date]["cases"])}
        catch(e){rowOpp.push("0")};
      try {rowRes.push(agentData[agent][date]["resolved"])}
        catch(e){rowRes.push("0")};
      try {rowFtr.push(agentData[agent][date]["resolved"] / agentData[agent][date]["cases"])}
        catch(e){rowFtr.push("0")};
    
    });
    
    opportunities.push(rowOpp);
    resolutions.push(rowRes);
    ftr.push(rowFtr);
  }
  
  
  // BUILDING HEADERS
  
  var headerOpp = ["Opportunities"]
  var headerRes = ["Resolutions"]
  var headerFtr = ["FTR"]
  
  dateRange.forEach( (date) => {
                    headerOpp.push("");
                    headerRes.push("");
                    headerFtr.push("");
                    });
  
  dateRange.unshift("");
  
  // BUILDING FINAL REPORT
  
  var report = [dateRange,headerOpp]
  opportunities.forEach((row) => {report.push(row)})
  report.push(headerRes)
  resolutions.forEach((row) => {report.push(row)})
  report.push(headerFtr)
  ftr.forEach((row) => {report.push(row)})
  
  return report
}
```

This will populate the "Report" tab with these dynamic tables.

This is only a framework for you to use as a learning tool, or to adapt to your specific needs.

#### Reference material for Apps Script

- [Main page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs)
- [Spreadsheet reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: Interesting! However, MaxDate is coming 1 less than last date in sheet. for e.g. my Max Date was April 1 2020, but it is calculating till Mar 31st 2020. Also, it is displaying counts per day, not grouping per Year-Month. How do you change that?

Comment: Hello, I would love to help, but I won't be able to help more on this question. I wrote this as an example to show you the type of things you can accomplish with Apps Script as it seems that you are running into the limits of formulas. These further questions are getting **out of the scope of the original question**. The best thing is to try and experiment with this code if you want, and if you get stuck, ask another question. Apologies not to be able to help more.