# Create Percentage Table from 2 other tables - Google Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Is there a way to calculate a 3rd crosstab Table containing percentages from 2 crosstab tables created from Google Queries? Initially i was stacking the 2 queries together using braces, but found that if there were row or column mismatches, then both the table queries would result in #VALUE error. So separated the 2 tables with 100 grouped rows between them. I want to calculate FTR percentage table below these tables.

Here is an [FTRTable](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gOvcpeTNxwwqu6-jFQJDqPD1PlX1oL2Z8cOpjNHB0Q0/edit?usp=sharing) with Edit access.

You can refer to my earlier related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198250/ftr-calculation-using-google-query-function/64227657?noredirect=1#comment113660556_64227657).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula for FTR table:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(QUERY({QUERY(
 {InputData!D3:D&"♦"&InputData!C3:C, InputData!B3:F, InputData!D3:D&
 IF(InputData!D3:D="",,"♥"&TEXT(InputData!D3:D, "dd/mm/yyyy"))}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col3,Col7,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5 != 'lost'     
  group by Col1,Col4,Col3,Col7"),
IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(QUERY({InputData!D3:D&"♦"&InputData!C3:C, InputData!B3:F}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col3,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5 != 'lost'     
  group by Col1,Col4,Col3"),,1), 
QUERY({InputData!D3:D&"♦"&InputData!C3:C, InputData!B3:F}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5 != 'lost' 
    and Col6  = 'yes' 
  group by Col1"), 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col4,Col3,Col6/Col5"), 
 "select Col2,max(Col3) 
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1 
  label Col2'FTR%' 
  format max(Col3)'#.00%'")), "(\d+♥)", ))
```

[image: 0]

---

and all 3 tables in one formula fully dynamic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IFNA(
 HLOOKUP(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(InputData!A3:F, 
 "select D,count(B) 
  where D is not null 
    and year(D)="&C1&" 
    and E!='lost' 
  group by D 
  pivot C 
  label D 'NO OF ISSUES'")), 1), TRANSPOSE(QUERY({InputData!A3:F}, 
 "select Col4,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5!='lost' 
    and Col6 = 'yes' 
  group by Col4 
  pivot Col3 
  label Col4 'NO OF ISSUES'")), ROW(A1:A10000), 0)), 
 "where Col1 <> '#REF!'")), 
 "format Col1'm/d/yyyy'")); 
 SPLIT(REPT(" ♠", COLUMNS(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(InputData!A3:F, 
 "select D,count(B) 
  where D is not null
    and year(D)="&C1&" 
    and E!='lost' 
  group by D 
  pivot C 
  label D 'TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES'")))), "♠"); 
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(InputData!A3:F, 
 "select D,count(B) 
  where D is not null
    and year(D)="&C1&" 
    and E!='lost' 
  group by D 
  pivot C 
  label D 'TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES'")); 
 SPLIT(REPT(" ♠", COLUMNS(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(InputData!A3:F, 
 "select D,count(B) 
  where D is not null
    and year(D)="&C1&" 
    and E!='lost' 
  group by D 
  pivot C 
  label D 'TOTAL OPPORTUNITIES'")))), "♠");
 REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(QUERY({QUERY(
 {InputData!D3:D&"♦"&InputData!C3:C, InputData!B3:F, InputData!D3:D&
 IF(InputData!D3:D="",,"♥"&TEXT(InputData!D3:D, "m/d/yyyy"))}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col3,Col7,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5 != 'lost'     
  group by Col1,Col4,Col3,Col7"),
IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(QUERY({InputData!D3:D&"♦"&InputData!C3:C, InputData!B3:F}, 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col3,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5 != 'lost'     
  group by Col1,Col4,Col3"),,1), 
QUERY({InputData!D3:D&"♦"&InputData!C3:C, InputData!B3:F}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and year(Col4)="&C1&" 
    and Col5 != 'lost' 
    and Col6  = 'yes' 
  group by Col1"), 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col4,Col3,Col6/Col5"), 
 "select Col2,max(Col3) 
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1 
  label Col2'FTR%' 
  format max(Col3)'#.00%'")), "(\d+♥)", )})
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ThOeSQEurliWYYW3XKUSHFJ_zYJDJ_fPkyryJINsBxU/edit#gid=1013873379)

Comment: This is gigantic and awesome! Thanks. However on my productions sheet of A to T columns and 6652 rows, it gives following error `Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (8492).` though already 50k rows have been inserted and sometimes `Formula Parse error`. I have tried changing the references. What could be the problem? Could it be that some of the functions are not able to handle large data?

Comment: I have added the production table columns to a new Sheet called `Study Report` and pasted the formula under `Clubbed Tables` in O column of `Tables` sheet (next to your formula). Now i am getting `In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.` I think i am confused in correctly mapping the Col1, Col2...etc., after REGEXREPLACE part in your formula.

Comment: Just need a way to add TOTAL Rows column. For FTR% table, it would be Average for each column.

Comment: is it possible to add totals to each table? and is there a way to show blank, if for a year, data is not present? i am trying to add totals like this query, but not sure where to add it in the huge formula. for e.g. for 1st table, `{TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Study Report'!$A:$T,"SELECT COUNT(B) WHERE YEAR(S) = "& $C$1 &" AND O != 'NO - all fine' AND L != 'Cancelled' GROUP BY S LABEL COUNT(B) 'TOTAL'",0))}`

Comment: `NO OF ISSUES` table calculations is not correct. See `ONION METHOD` Sheet.

Comment: Hi @player0 i was finally able to add TOTALs rows to all 3 tables. However, can you help me with removing the `#VALUE` error that shows up when data is not available for a selected Year say `2016`?

Comment: what is the reason for using the `HLOOKUP(INDEX(` Combination for `No of Issues` table? It yeilds the same table that one of the inner query generates.

Comment: @sifar on the picture from the answer you can notice that first table has one column less than 2nd and 3rd table. when creating constructed array {} all parts/ranges/tables needs to be of same size otherwise you will get Array Literal error. option is either to add missing column or to use HLOOKUP to map it (and empty column is added automatically)

Comment: Yes, i understood most of your formula now, but how do i tackle the situation when for a particular date, if data is not available, some of the tables donot generate and may result in just their column names or a `#VALUE` error?

Comment: Also, if you see the formula in `Tables` Sheet, under `Clubbed Tables`, it works in my production sheet, but does not seem to work in the `FTR Table Spreadsheet`, though the Study Report columns are the same. What could be the reason?

Comment: At the place of `INDEX`, i replaced it with `TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(EDATE(date(C1,1,1),SEQUENCE(1,12,)))),"SELECT Col1 LABEL Col1 'NO OF ISSUES' FORMAT Col1 'yyyy-mmm'"))` for `HLOOKUP` to use. Works well for other years, but still the `#VALUE` error for say, `Year 2016`. Not able to under reason for this error.